# Formula Limitations for IDs for "Create Record" in Screenflow?

Tags: formula, salesforce-id, screen-flow

I'm getting an issue with a formula field that references the correct account ID in a screenflow. This type of formula worked for an autolaunched flow. I converted the flow to screenflow and it now the formula doesn't work. The formula is pretty simple if-then statement. If(ISNULL(GetAccount), CreateAccount, GetAccount).

For context, when on a custom object called "Import Record", the user will click a button to process a screenflow. It needs to use the ID of an account listed on the record. If the account doesn't exist in our system, it creates a new account using the "create records" component within the flow. The CreateAccount is the ID from this create account component. Otherwise, it uses the Id from the Get Records component. The formula is used in the flow after the "create records" component.

This is where the account is retrieved. I've also added a fault process.
[image: get account flow sample]

The formula looks like this.
[image: formula]

Later in the flow, we create a different object record that references the formula to obtain the correct account ID.
[image: formula assigned]

Unfortunately the formula just pulls "null" if using the ID from the create records component. I'm curious why I cannot source the IDs from these components in a formula in a screenflow? Is this a known limitation?

I'm assigning variables as a workaround and it's working so far. I just want more understanding of why these formula fields work for different flow types.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how you have the Create element configured?

Comment: I added some screenshots above

Comment: is `Create Account` an sobject or an Id?

Comment: When I choose "AccountID from Create_Account" from the "Insert a Resource" search bar when creating a formula, it populates as {!Create_Account}. It's supposed to be an ID.